# Sending UDP packets seems to cause loss on incoming packets on different NIC

Tags: windows-server-2012, udp, audio-streaming, packet-loss

I'm running Windows Server 2012 with an audio streaming application that streams over UDP. Another application is receiving audio that's also streamed over UDP, but arrives through a separate NIC. However it seems that the more packets the first application transmits, the more incoming packets get lost in the second application.

The total CPU load of the system is about 40%, so it should have plenty of headroom.
Does this issue make sense in any way? Is there something I could do to improve this behaviour?

Comment: Well consider updating NIC drivers and/or firmware of the BIOS and such too but I'd run a Wireshark trace on each interface and be sure there's not something else causing packet overhead you could turn off.

Comment: Also, you might tell us what audio streaming app you are using in case someone knows of any specific settings with that app to adjust to help with such problems.

Comment: We need more detail before this can be answered. Some starters: Is the server physical or virtual? What make/model of NICs? What apps are doing the streaming?

Comment: All data coming over the same internet connection?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a lot more digging I seem to have found a solution to the problem.

Microsoft provided a hotfix for Windows Server 2012 that allows bypassing the Base Filtering Engine for incoming multicast streams: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2808584/datagram-loss-when-you-run-a-multicast-receiver-application-in-windows

However, the hotfix is not available for Windows Server 2012 R2. But then I found this blogpost: https://personalnexus.wordpress.com/2017/02/06/the-case-of-multicast-message-loss-on-windows-server-2012-r2/

> So by now I have a solid checklist of things to configure on our servers and ensure in our applications that consume multicast messages to make sure everything runs smoothly and message loss is kept at acceptable levels. Yet, on our latest Windows Server 2012 R2 machines I had applications experiencing serious datagram loss as the amount of network traffic (in general, not just multicast) on the machine increased increased.
>
> I researched the problem online and got the tips you’d expect: get latest NIC drivers, increase NIC receive buffer sizes, turn on offloads, turn on receive-side scaling, fine-tune receive-side scaling, increase socket buffer sizes etc. Of course, I had already tried all those things, and none of them had worked

The solution according to the blogpost:

> Unfortunately, the document describes an issue in Windows Server 2012 and the hotfix available there cannot be installed on Windows Server 2012 R2. Fortunately, it doesn’t have to be. You can just set the registry key and the Base Filtering Engine supports it out of the box.

```
New-ItemProperty HKLM:\System\CurrentControlSet\services\Tcpip\Parameters\ -Name UdpExemptPortRange -Value "XXXX-YYYY" -PropertyType MultiString -Force
```

Until now the streams run fine again. Apparantly the BFE can't handle the vast amount of incoming UDP traffic when there's also a fair amount of outgoing UDP traffic.

Comment: Happy to hear that my blogpost was helpful :-)